# $f$ is an entire function, then $f(\mathbb{C})$ is closed

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, fake-proofs

While trying to prove "$f$ is an entire function such that $|f(z)| \to \infty, as |z|\to \infty$, then $f(\mathbb{C}) $ is closed"

I accidentally showed that

"$f$ is an entire function, then $f(\mathbb{C})$ is closed" I know this is not a correct statement, but I need to know where did I gone wrong and I need some hints to correct the proof...

##### the proof:-

Let $a$ be a cluster point of $f(\mathbb{C})$, then $\exists f(z_n) \in f(\mathbb{C})$ such that $f(z_n) \to a$

Now consider $$g(z): B[a,1] \to \mathbb{C}$$
$$g(z)=|f(z)-a|$$

This is a continuous real valued function on a  compact set and hence attains a minimum, suppose it attains its minimum on the boundary, say the minimum is $r>0$, but since we have
$f(z_n)\to a$, I can find a $f(z_k) \in B[a,1]$ such that $|f(z_k)-a|<r$
and hence the minimum is attained in the open ball $B(a,1)$, and hence by Minimum modulus principle the minimum is zero,

$$\implies \exists w , s.t f(w)=a$$

Which implies $a \in f(\mathbb{C})$ and hence $f(\mathbb{C})$ is Closed.

where did the proof gone wrong and what can I do to rectify and give a proof of the original statement.

Comment: $f(z) = e^z$ with $a=0$ is a counterexample. Can you see where your proof fails?

Comment: Why not find the error yourself?  Consider the entire function $f(z) = e^z$ with $f(\mathbb C) = \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ not closed.  See where your proof goes wrong in that case.

Comment: You are assuming that $z_n \in B[a,1]$.

Comment: @MartinR I need to see where did I made a mistake

Comment: @geetha290krm No mam, I am not assuming that, I am assuming only $f(z_k)$ for large $k$ belongs to $B[a,1]$, since $f(z_k) \to a$, I think this is correct...

Comment: $g$ is defined on $B[a,1]$. So you cannot use $g(z_n)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm yes mam, I understand now, I am assuming that $z_k \in B[a,1] $ to see $g(z_n)$, and proceeding, but nothing guarantees the existence of $z_k \in B[a,1]$... can you give me a hint to how to proceed and give a proof of the original statement?

Comment: If $f$ is an entire function such that $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $|z|\to \infty$ then $f$ is a polynomial and its range is all of $\mathbb C$

Comment: as far as *"what can I do to rectify"*, the $f$ in your first sentence can be extended to the sphere $\cong \mathbb C_\infty$ so $f\big(\mathbb C_\infty\big)$ is closed for reasons of compactness.  And the complement of $f\big(\mathbb C_\infty\big)$ is open and lives in $\mathbb C$, hence its complement in $\mathbb C$, given by $f\big(\mathbb C\big)$ is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your seqeunce $z_n$ has  a bounded subsequence (because if $|z_n| \to \infty$ the $|a|=\lim |f(z_n)|=\infty$,  a contradiction). If $z_{n_k} \to z$ then $a=f(z)$ so $a \in f(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: and hence $f(\mathbb{C})$ is closed and by open mapping theorem it is open, as it is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, $f(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}$ and hence f is onto